# why bootstrap_reboot not working in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

It's been days, tried all the recommendations I've seen online but the bootstrap reboot not working in reactjs.

I also tried to put it inside my public/index.hmtl as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Also, tried to import it as

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css';
```

Please help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: did you try changing the order?

Comment: Nope. not working though.

Comment: Isn't bootstrap reboot used within bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: @SILENT yes but its not working. as you can see in the screenshot above. right now, I am trying to re-order but none works yet.

Comment: Can you show all items above the _reboot.scss screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com)

**And copy the CDN links to the index.html from the public folder** . Read the documentation and choose your classes.
**Note**: *the class attribute is called className in React Component*

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your entry file:

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

And also instead of using class, use className as React recommend.